# error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index 'ModuleType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have types

```
type Link = {
  type: number | string;
  productIds: Array<string>;
};

export type ModuleType = {
  '@type': string;
  title: string;
  text: string;
  position: string;
  backgroundStyle: string;
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
  background: File;
  link: Link;
};
```

```
const formDataType = formData[link].type;
```

Here `formData` has a type ModuleType and I'm trying take object key with a string, but I have got an error in TS: `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ModuleType'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ModuleType'.`
I need take link key from the object

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to tell TypeScript that the keyword name is a key of type ModuleType.

For that you have to write like this,

```
let name : keyof ModuleType = 'Whatever value it contains';

const formDataType = formData[name].type;

//  or

const formDataType = formData[<keyof ModuleType>name].type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can refer an object as its type was **any**:

```
(<any>obj)
```

Example:

```
const obj:{xx:string, yy:number} = {xx:'hello', yy:123};
 
const keyName = 'xx';

obj[keyName] = 'new val';   // <-- will throw an error

(<any> obj)[keyName] = 'new val';  // <-- will do fine
```